# Powershell String in File Name

Tags: powershell

This the code I am using, when the read host appears I can type anything I want such as Hello and it will create a Hello.txt file on my desktop.

How do I get it so that read host will understand my variables? So can call them and say $firstname_$lastname_file4

and then on another occasion could put $firstname_$ID_april2021

My variables will always be the same, i just want to be able to use them when creating a file name

```
$firstname = 'John'
$lastname = 'Smith'
$ID = 324230

$filename = Read-Host "What would you like to call the file?"

New-Item "C:\\Myarea\Desktop\$filename"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ExpandString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```
$filenameExpanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($filename)
```

**Be careful though** - `ExpandString` will execute *any* valid subexpression included in the raw string, so if your user enters `$(Remove-Item C:\Windows\System32)`, your script will execute it for them.

To safeguard against such input, we can use PowerShell's parser to inspect the string expression for us:

```
function Test-SafeExpandableString {
  param([string]$LiteralStringExpression)

  # Construct StringExpression AST
  $emptyExtent = [Activator]::CreateInstance([psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.Language.EmptyScriptPosition'))
  $stringExpressionAST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.ExpandableStringExpressionAst]::new($emptyExtent, $LiteralStringExpression, [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantType]::DoubleQuoted)

  # Inspect result AST's nested expressions
  foreach($expr in $stringExpressionAST.NestedExpressions){
    if($expr -isnot [System.Management.Automation.Language.VariableExpressionAst]){
      # There's a non-variable sub expression in the string, it's not safe
      return $false
    }
  }

  return $true
}
```

And now we can safely proceed:

```
$filename = Read-Host "What would you like to call the file?"

if(Test-SafeExpandableString $filename){
  $filenameExpanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($filename)
  New-Item "C:\path\to\$filenameExpanded"
}
else {
  Write-Error "Only variable expressions allowed!"
}
```

You could modify the `Test-SafeExpandableString` function to accept a list of variable names to test, I will leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Thank you Mathias! How would this need to look in my code if I wanted to name the file with their First Name, Last Name and then type 'April2021'

So would it would look like John_Smith_April2021.txt

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr You'd enter `${firstname}_${lastname}_${ID}.ps1` in the console then